# VBA Application-defined or object-defined error when copying

Tags: vba

I am writing a code which is to copy from data from another workbook to the current open workbook. However, I am encountering the Application-defined or object-defined error which I kept thinking but unable to find a reason as to why. That is why I decided to post my problem here and hopefully get some help. Please find my code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyDataSEA()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim destWs As Worksheet
Set destWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim Report As Workbook
Set Report = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\John\Documents\My Docs\Report 2020 EMEA_SEA_SA Region.xlsx")
Dim sourceWs As Worksheet
Set sourceWs = Report.Worksheets("Raw")
    
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = sourceWs.Range("A" & sourceWs.Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row

Dim outRow As Long
outRow = 2

'Copying Header of source
destWs.Rows(1).EntireRow.Value = sourceWs.Rows(1).EntireRow.Value

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If sourceWs.Cells(i, 6) = "INDONESIA" Or sourceWs.Cells(i, 6) = "MALAYSIA" Or sourceWs.Cells(i, 6) = "THAILAND" Or sourceWs.Cells(i, 6) = "VIETNAM" _
        Or sourceWs.Cells(i, 6) = "CAMBODIA" Or sourceWs.Cells(i, 6) = "MYANMAR" Or sourceWs.Cells(i, 6) = "PHILIPPINES" Or sourceWs.Cells(i, 6) = "SINGAPORE" Then
            destWs.Rows(outRow).EntireRow.Value = sourceWs.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
            outRow = outRow + 1
        End If
    Next i

Report.Close False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am getting an error on this row

```
destWs.Rows(outRow).EntireRow.Value = sourceWs.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
```

The value of outRow was 25728 and i was 44246 when the error encountered. The number of columns of the source document is 74518.

Comment: Try on the debug your 2 rows, use `.Address` instead of value, see which one throws the error.

Comment: Also look in Report 2020 EMEA_SEA_SA Region.xlsx and look for merged cells on the Raw sheet in line 44246 (or something else - this will catch your eye, this line is somewhat different from the previous one)

Comment: @JohnSUN can't see any problem on that line. When i tried running the code, the error is there again but the value of outRow and i is different this time.

Comment: @Damian Ok I will try

Comment: Different? Hmmm. Is your target sheet (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")) clean?

Comment: @JohnSUN yes, I select all and clear all for target sheet then select all and clear formatting for source sheet but error is still happening